# Can a full time employee who also owns a side LLC claim "self-employed" deductions?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, small-business, self-employment

I am working full time for a corporation in NYC (I have w2). I also own my own side Educational LLC (EdTech) which has claimed $0.00 in income for 2018, but has accrued several thousand in startup expenses to get it off the ground.

TurboTax has a "Self-Employed" designation on its site while filing taxes. Using this, I've tripled my tax refund on "Self-Employed" business expenses.

They are indeed my LLC's business expenses, but not sure if I can still claim them if I'm not working full time on my LLC, and if the LLC has made $0.00.

Comment: You say you "tripled my tax return", but I don't think that is what you care about.  Having 3 times as much tax paperwork is usually considered negative.  Check whether perhaps you meant "tax refund" and not "return".

Comment: It will come down to whether your side LLC is a real business. The test is complex, but the general idea is this -- it's a real business if you have a reasonable expectation of making an actual profit in a reasonable amount of time. Otherwise, it's a hobby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an accountant or tax prep person. You should ask your accountant to verify.

Yes, you can claim any verifiable expenses and end up with a loss. [Schedule C instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040sc.pdf) for Line 31 (page C-13) notes

> Figuring your net profit or loss. If your expenses (including the
>   expenses you report on line 30) are more than your gross income, do
>   not enter your loss on line 31 **until you have applied the at-risk
>   rules and the passive activity loss rules. To apply these rules,
>   follow the instructions in Line 32 and the Instructions for Form 8582**.
>   After applying those rules, the amount on line 31 will be your loss,
>   and it may be smaller than the amount you figured by subtracting line
>   30 from line 29.

The caution further down notes

> If you enter a loss on line 31, you **may have an excess business loss.
>   Use Form 461** to figure your excess business loss.

Follow all those instructions, and you should be good. I would not try to go for business use of home or other potentially questionable expenses. Personally, I'd only include what I had verified receipts and documentation (e.g., business use of vehicle) that can be easily proven.